# »ein und dieselbe Nachricht« vs. »eine und dieselbe Nachricht«

Tags: phrase, grammatical-case, gender

Ich lese gerade *Miteinander Reden 1* von schulz von thun*. Im Buch steht:

> Für mich selbst war es eine faszinierende »Entdeckung«, die ich in ihrer Tragweite erst nach und nach erkannt habe, dass **ein und dieselbe Nachricht** stets viele Botschaften gleichzeitig enthält.

Sollte es nicht *ein**e** und dieselbe Nachricht* heißen, weil das Wort *Nachricht* feminin ist?

Comment: In dieser Konstellation wird das "e" eigentlich immer weggelassen, weil der Bezug durch das "dieselbe" hergestellt wird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An sich hast du Recht - es müsste eigentlich *eine und dieselbe Nachricht* heißen (Es *kann* auch durchaus so verwendet werden, wäre grammatikalisch richtig, aber ungewöhnlich).

*Ein und [die|der|das]selbe* ist allerdings ein **stehender Ausdruck**, daher bezieht sich das "ein" nicht mehr auf das Substantiv "Nachricht" und wird deshalb nicht mit ihm flektiert.

Im Duden habe ich dazu auf die Schnelle nur ein Beispiel gefunden, das beide Verwendungen erlaubt:

> wir sind einer Meinung, ein[er] und derselben Meinung

Die Flektion bei "ein" wegzulassen, ist allerdings wesentlich gebräuchlicher.

canoo.net ist etwas gesprächiger:

> ein und derselbe
>
> Die Paarformel ein und derselbe/dieselbe/dasselbe dient der Verstärkung. Dabei bleibt ein meist ungebeugt:
>
> - ein und dieselbe Ursache
> - aus ein und derselben Quelle
> - mit ein und demselben Partner
>
> Selten wird ein auch gebeugt:
>
> - eine und dieselbe Ursache
> - aus einer und derselben Quelle
> - mit einem und demselben Partner